# Google Chrome gives `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'` error even though a specific URL is set

Tags: angular, express, google-chrome, http, cors

I have a web app written with Angular 9 for the frontend and nodejs for the backend.

My Express JS server is using the CORS middleware configured as follows:

```
const corsOptions = {
        origin: [
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://attendance.nas.i.example.com"
        ],
        credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

My angular http request looks like this:

```
static BASE_URL : string = "https://db-nas.i.example.com:3300";
static DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { withCredentials: true };

getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(ApiService.BASE_URL+'/users', ApiService.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
}
```

**Even though I have configured express to send explicit CORS origin header Google Chrome throws the following error in the console:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://db-nas.i.example.com:3300/users' from origin 'https://attendance.nas.i.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

**Firefox, Opera and Edge work without any problems.**

For clarification:

My frontend is accessed by `https://attendance.nas.i.example.com`

My backend is accessed by `https://db-nas.i.example.com:3300`

The request works with Firefox

Logging with the `morgan` `express`-middleware outputs:

```
GET /users 403 https://attendance.nas.i.example.com -
```

for the following log format:

```
:method :url :status :res[Access-Control-Allow-Origin] :res[Set-Cookie]
```

Note that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set correctly. The `403` respose is also correct in this context.

**UPDATE**

It seems to be a problem with the specific chrome installation. Even YouTube does not work and gives the same error message in the console. On a different computer it works in chrome. Reinstalling chrome did not help.

Version is 83.0.4103.116

Comment: set this. ` res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Comment: @sibabratswain why should I set the CORS header to `*` if chrome explicitly states that it must not be `*`?

Comment: @sibabratswain I tried it anyway but the error remains

Comment: Did you check which cors header your API returns with the network debugger, both for FF and chrome?

Comment: As a workaround I guess you could return your requester's domain in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to satisfy wildcard error. Also, you may try to use `HttpInterceptor` instead of using `withCredentials` right in your request. Thus you may catch OPTIONS request which would also have this header

Comment: Also, there is a chance that your changes to send credentials from Angular were not taken during serve as error may have been thrown and in browser it would look like everything OK (check https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response there is a note about options to the request)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the specific chrome installation. Not even YouTube seems to work. The website work on other computers in chrome.

Comment: as per your explanation request originates from https://db-nas.i.example.com:3300/users . So in your express js CORS rules, specify along with the port number . it should resolve

Comment: maybe... an extension you are using might be overriding the security options? or a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script? have you tried in an incognito window?

Comment: @CodeMind the frontend on `https://attendance.nas.i.example.com` is running on port `80`. Only the port of the express based backend is running on port `3300`.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation in Mozilla MDN

> For a CORS request with credentials, in order for browsers to expose the response >to frontend JavaScript code, both the server (using the Access-Control-Allow-?>Credentials header) and the client (by setting the credentials mode for the XHR, >Fetch, or Ajax request) must indicate that they’re opting in to including >credentials.

So basically you have 2 options here:

**Option 1:**
On frontend explicitly set the withCredentials parameter in xhr request like so

```
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true); 
xhr.withCredentials = true; 
xhr.send(null);
```

**Option 2:**
Disable credentials mode in the express server:

```
//.....

const corsOptions = {
        origin: [
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://attendance.nas.i.example.com"
        ],
        credentials: false
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//.....
```

Comment: I'm already using option 1. I have added the angular http request now so you can see.

Comment: @fal.sch I guess you need to have a look at Network tab. My guess is that request that fails is OPTIONS preflight request which is usually made by Chrome.